# Read all bytes from socket in c

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Hello i need to read all data from socket, have such function

```
void handle_socket(int sockfd) {
    int len;
    int n;
    char buf[1024];
    n = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0);
    while (n > 0) {
        buf[n] = '\0';
        printf("%s", buf);
        n = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0);
    }
    printf("Exiting\n");
}
```

But i can't see `Exiting` in terminal, what i am do wrong?
Socket `sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`

 **PS** i need to read response from POP3 server i try to find `\r\n.\r\n` but i can't be sure that this string will be at one buffer(for example `\r\n` at 1st buffer and `.\r\n` at 2nd

Comment: Is the client closing the socket at some point?

Comment: @Mat yes, after exiting from programm

Answer (score 2):

recv() function doesn't return 0 (EOF) untill process on the other end close connection and there is no data left to read. So you will see "Exiting" when the other process close connection.

Your function override old data by new one. You should decide whether you put a limit on the size of buffer or dynamically expand memory for new data. I don't know what your restrictions are, but I recommend to create FILE instance by calling fdopen() and work with standard functions like fgetc, fgets or getLine.